# ActiveMQ as an MQTT broker and read message directly from it without the client

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

So I am using ActiveMQ as a MQTT broker like this:

```java
TransportConnector mqtt = new TransportConnector();
mqtt.setName(mqttBrokerConfig.getBrokerName());
URI uri = new URI("mqtt://some ip");
mqtt.setUri(uri);
final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.setUseJmx(false);        // Disable JMX for secure purpose
broker.setPersistent(mqttBrokerConfig.getPersistence());
broker.setAdvisorySupport(mqttBrokerConfig.getAdvisorySupport());
if(mqttBrokerConfig.getEnableLogin()) {
    SimpleAuthenticationPlugin authenticationPlugin = loadLogins();
    broker.setPlugins(new BrokerPlugin[]{authenticationPlugin});
}
broker.setUseShutdownHook(true);
broker.addConnector(mqtt);
```

I need to accept MQTT message from outside, read the message from the broker, and send it to Kafka.
Right now I in the same JVM I created a MQTT client, and connect the broker through 127.0.0.1. Going through the internal network still has some overhead, and the connection could be lost sometimes.

Since the client is in the same JVM as the broker is there a way to read the MQTT messages directly without going through the network? If ActiveMQ does not support such feature is there another java MQTT broker that support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [VM transport](https://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference) is what you want. If your client uses the VM transport that should eliminate any overhead incurred from going through a normal network connection.

In order to use the VM transport you'll need to use the OpenWire JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ. Your remote MQTT client(s) can send messages to the embedded ActiveMQ broker and your local clients in the same VM can then receive those messages.

Other protocol clients (e.g. MQTT, AMQP, STOMP, etc.) will not be able to use the VM transport as it requires ActiveMQ-specific integration.

Comment: Does VM transport require all the clients within the same jvm? Currently I am using Paho mqtt client within the same jvm, but it does not accept vm:// url. Is there a specific client that support that? I still cannot find any tutorial for activemq to accept message from external source(not in the same jvm), and receive it using VM. Many thanks

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I did not find the accept button. This solves my question!

Comment: You should create a new question instead of adding more comments here.